# Sed to convert absolute to relative link in markdown file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, markdown

I got a couple of markdown files and I need to replace the absolute link to relative link for the images present in it.

Assumptions:

- The image syntax is only in markdown, i.e. `![]()` and not HTML or any other format
- All the image paths ends in the image directory, `abc/xyz/images/sample.png`

Example:

Absolute link:
`![alt text](https://github.com/a/b/c..../images/sample.png)`

Should be replaced with:
`![alt text](images/sample.png)`

I thought of the following steps:

1. Identify lines starting with `![` (ignoring the corner cases)
2. Traverse over the text in `()`
3. Replace everything before 2nd last `/` with empty string

How can I implement it or any other better approach using `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, which implements the logic you outlined:

```sh
sed 's|\(!\[[^]]\+](\)[^)]\+/\([^)]\+/[^)]\+)\)|\1\2|' input
```

Using the `-E` option saves just a few characters:

```sh
sed -E 's|(!\[[^]]+]\()[^)]+/([^)]+/[^)]+\))|\1\2|' input
```

---

As regards `-E`, it looks like it's POSIX:

```
       -E, -r, --regexp-extended

              use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use
              POSIX -E).
```